# How to overload a function which calls an overloaded version of itself?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

```
    Fraction Fraction::pow (Fraction frac, int power)
    {
        Fraction temp;
    temp.num = pow(frac.num, power);
    temp.den = pow(frac.den, power);

    return (temp);
    }
    // Assume that num and den are float and cmath is included
```

During the instance of `pow` inside the `Fraction::pow,` it takes `float`, `int` as an input and should give out `float` but instead it takes `Fraction` as an input and throws an error.

Comment: Could you post the exact signatures for all your `pow` functions in that class, as well as all the constructors, copy-assignment operators, and conversion operators?

Comment: Show the second overloaded definition of `pow`.

Comment: As @Mat says post the class & function definitions, your `Fraction` class most likely has a conversion constructor which is used for implicit conversion resulting in call to incorrect function, to determine Why this happens,You need to show us the details Mat says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try calling the global scope `pow` function (which I guess is the one you want):

```
temp.num = ::pow(frac.num, power);
temp.den = ::pow(frac.den, power);
```

The scoping operator (`::`) with nothing on its left side will invoke the global scope. Of course, since you are including `<cmath>` you should also be able to call them in the `std` namespace:

```
temp.num = std::pow(frac.num, power);
temp.den = std::pow(frac.den, power);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/ no overloaded method takes a float and an integer, the only one taking a float as first argument also takes a float as second argument.

```
float pow (float base, float exponent);
```

Does your Fraction class have another overloaded version of pow?